# Is it possible to be reimbursed for a car detail due to an unsanitary job site?

Tags: work-environment, human-resources, unprofessional-behavior

At my job I drive to, they have an ant infestation inside (kitchen, bathroom, bedrooms) and outside the property (parking lot & driveway) that had reached inside my car. This problem was ongoing for more than a week and I personally took the next step of washing it without consulting if I could be reimbursed for the fees and I ask now afterwards. I have proof, videos, receipts, and even testimony. Is it possible!?

Comment: This is a question of company policy and practice. We can't answer it for you. Ask your employer.

Comment: Why would you ask your question here instead of asking your boss/manager? Wouldn't that be the most expedient way to get an answer? How would we know if your company will reimburse your expenses?

Answer (score 2):

#### Of course it's possible

You just need to ask your manager.  If I were your manager you telling me would be all the proof I needed to approve it.